# Correct way to share a view in the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, partials, renderpartial

I'm a Ruby-on-Rails newbie, just starting out.

I have an MVC called "account_types", generated via scaffold to produce:

- controllers/account_types_controller.rb
- helpers/account_types_helper.rb
- models/account_type.rb
- views/account_types/_form, edit, index etc...

Going to localhost:3000/account_types gives me the index view.

What I'd like to do is display the same data as selected from the account_types index method in the application index page as a list.

I wrote a new view called account_types/_list.html_erb as follows:

```
<ul>
<% @account_types.each do |account| %>
    <li><% account.label %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I then edited home/index.html.erb (This is based on examples given in other questions on SO):

```
<%= render :partial => 'account_types/list', :module_types => @module_types %>
```

However I get

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

and the error displays the code from account_types/_list.html.erb where I've written

```
<% @account_types.each do |account| %>
```

The scaffolded views work fine, why aren't mine?

Are partials the right thing to use here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is the correct way to define an application-wide partial and its variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869291/what-is-the-correct-way-to-define-an-application-wide-partial-and-its-variables) says to use a `before_filter` on `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `:module_types` to partial, but use `account_types`. As I can see you just need to change your index.html.erb to:

```
<%= render :partial => 'account_types/list', :account_types => @module_types %>
```

Comment: Sorry, as above I've confused everyone with module_types - that was something else I was trying - it should have been account_types.

`<%= render :partial => 'account_types/list', :account_types => @account_types %> still gives the same error message.

Comment: I've created a new project to recreate this problem. I've set everything up as before.

If I don't add (amp)account_types = AccountType.all to home_controller.rb, I get the same error about nil.each

If I add (amp)account_types = AccountType.all to home_controller.rb then I get an li for each record, but no lists of data (which is strange in itself). However, (amp)account_types is already defined in account_types_controller.rb, so in the interests of DRY, can I somehow use the index controller from account_types instead of having to rewrite it in the home controller to use it in the home view?

Comment: I think I have it working now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869291/what-is-the-correct-way-to-define-an-application-wide-partial-and-its-variables says to use a `before_filter` on  `ApplicationController`. I've put that in, and suddenly the `account_types` variable is available to every controller. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partials for this if you want, though it would be unnecessary in this case as far as I can tell (they are for sharing chunks of code between several views). In order to get this code to work you'll need to define `@account_types` in your controller with something like

```
@account_types = AccountType.all
```

You can see exact line in your `account_types_controller.rb` under `index` action. `:module_types => @module_types` is not necessary here, since I doubt you defined `@module_types` either *and* you don't use `module_types` in your partial at all.

It's obvious, that you don't understand how Rails works, so I suggest reading through a good tutorial (like [this one](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)) before you proceed with whatever you have in mind.

Comment: Oops. module_types was something else I was trying. It was supposed to be account_types. Sorry.

I've got `@account_types = AccountType.all` in the controller. The trouble is that my custom view can't seem to access the variable @account_types, so it is complaining that it's nil. How do I get my custom view to access @account_types the same way `AccountTypesController.index` works?

Comment: Well, you can forcefully pass it as with `:account_types => @account_types`, but then you'll need to change `@account_types` in your partial to `account_types`.